# Cannot send hidden input in $_POST PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, post

I have a table with users, when I click icon it redirects me to '/edit.php' where I have form:

```
<form action="form.php" class="form-horizontal col-xs-3" method="post">
        <p>Imię <input type="text" name="name" value='<?php echo $user["name"];?>' class="form-control input-sm"/></p>
        <p> Nazwisko <input type="text" name="surname" value='<?php echo $user["surname"];?>' class="form-control input-sm"/></p>
        <p> Wiek <input type="number" name="age" value='<?php echo $user["age"];?>' class="form-control input-sm"/></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="update" value="true"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="userId" value='<?php echo $user["id"]; }?>'/>
...
```

Hidden input called "update" is used in 'form.php' file to detect if request came from new or edit page:

```
if (isset($_POST["update"])){
...
```

And that is ok, it works.  But I have function update which builds updateQuery string:

```
function update($tableName, $name, $surname, $age, $departmentId, $userId){
        $updateQuery =  "UPDATE "
        .$tableName
        ." SET "
        ."name=".$name.", "."surname=".$surname.", "."age=".$age.","."department_id=".$departmentId.")"
        ." WHERE id=".$userId;
        echo $updateQuery;
        return $updateQuery;
    }
```

And I got error:

> Warning: Missing argument 6 for update(), called in C:\Users\Abc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject1\form.php on line 107 and defined in C:\Users\Abc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject1\form.php on line 48

And it seems to be like I can't get "userId" variable in this way: `(int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["userId"])`

But very interesting thing is, when I use it in 'echo' it works, for example:

```
echo (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["userId"])." is ID";
```

This is how I call update() method:

```
if (isset($_POST["update"])){
                echo (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["userId"])." is ID";
                $pdo->query(update("users", $pdo->quote(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"])), 
                    $pdo->quote(htmlspecialchars($_POST["surname"])),
                    (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["age"]), (int)htmlspecialchars($departmentRealId)),
                    (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["userId"]));

            }
```

And this is update() method code, which should build update query:

```
function update($tableName, $name, $surname, $age, $departmentId, $userId){
        $updateQuery =  "UPDATE "
        .$tableName
        ." SET "
        ."name=".$name.", "."surname=".$surname.", "."age=".$age.","."department_id=".$departmentId.")"
        ." WHERE id=".$userId;
        echo $updateQuery;
        return $updateQuery;
    }
```

And this is sample updateQuery which is created by update() method: `UPDATE users SET name='matt', surname='damon', age=56,department_id=2) WHERE id=`

Unfortunately, I don't know why, $userId parameter is not present. As you can see in code above: in line: `echo (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["userId"])." is ID";`
and in update() call: `(int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["age"]), (int)htmlspecialchars($departmentRealId)),
                        (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["userId"]));`
I do it in the same way - at least I don't see any difference, which could cause that parameter is not present.
I will be very happy if anybody helps me - thank you in advance.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="userId" value='<?php echo $user["id"]; }?>'/>. The { shouldn't be there.

Comment: @jeff
Even if I removed it (by <php? } ?> it other place, because its a part of earlier code), unfortunately id didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where bracket highlighting will come in handy, check out the line where you call update:

[image]

Notice how the update function does not include your `(int)htmlspecialchars($_POST['userId'])`.

Instead, you should use:

```
$pdo->query(update("users",
    $pdo->quote(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"])), 
    $pdo->quote(htmlspecialchars($_POST["surname"])),
    (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["age"]),
    (int)htmlspecialchars($departmentRealId),
    (int)htmlspecialchars($_POST["userId"])
));
```

Comment: Yeah now it works excellent, my innatention - thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1):

friend!

There are some problems about the code.

 First:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value='<?php echo $user["id"]; }?>'/>
```

You should remove the "**}**" from that! 
 
 
So it will be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?php echo $user["id"]; ?>"/>
```

Second, your function doesn't have quotes.
Change to:

```
function update($tableName, $name, $surname, $age, $departmentId, $userId){
        $updateQuery =  "UPDATE "
        .$tableName
        ." SET "
        ."name='".$name."', "."surname='".$surname."', "."age=".$age.","."department_id=".$departmentId.")"
        ." WHERE id=".$userId;
        echo $updateQuery;
        return $updateQuery;
    }
```

I mean:

```
"name='".$name."'
```

Every column text should have quotes, instead of:

```
Update (...) Set Name=Felipe
```

You should do:

```
Update (...) Set Name='Felipe'
```

Comment: I use "$pdo->quote(..)" when I called update() function - but you are right, it should be done inside function :)